# How to make a 2nd tab of XL file visible?

Tags: excel, qtp, hp-uft, vba

There are 2 tabs in my XL (VISA and MasterCard). I am able to read the data from  VISA and MasterCard tab. When my script read the data from 'MasterCard' tab [Which is a 2nd tab of my XL] it shows me 'VISA' tab [ It reads the data from 'MasterCard' correctly]. 
When script will read the data 'MasterCard' tab it should show 'MasterCard' tab NOT 'Visa' tab. I need this because I want a screen shot of both tab separately. 
NOTE: I am using UFT for reading XL file

Comment: Look into the code for where the name of the sheet is displayed. That's where the wrong name is given to the correct sheet. Change the displayed name directly in the code.

Comment: Please show us your VBA code.

Comment: `Sheets("MasterCard").Activate`

Comment: Are you using UFT to open Excel and try to read the data directly from an open Excel instance or are you loading the file as a UFT `Datatable` object?

Comment: @Dave Ah, the `excel-vba` tag was misleading me